Has anybody successfully installed a GPU on a Supermicro X11DPi-NT?
I installed a RTX3060 in slot 2. OS is RHEL 9.3.
In text mode the OS boots normally with no errors.
Starting Gnome 40.4.0 the GPU displayed garbled graphics, then returned to text mode.
Using the built in video ASpeed AST2500, Gnome is displayed normally, however performance for graphics intensive applications is poor.
I would like to hear from people who have successfully installed a GPU in the Supermicro X11DPi-NT, let me know what GPU was used.
Thank you

Can you provide some more details about what business problem you're trying to solve? Review the FAQ if you're not sure why I would be asking that
https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic
Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment. 
